# list of jars in tomcat+jpa+hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, tomcat7

I use tomcat 7, deployed there a web application with jpa and hibernate. What jars should be copied to make it work? My deployment constantly fails on "ClassNotFoundException" or "IncompatibleClassChangeError". 

I've got the following jars:

> antlr-2.7.6.jar
>   commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
>   dom4j-1.6.1.jar
>   hibernate-annotations.jar
>   hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
>   hibernate-entitymanager.jar
>   hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar 
>   javassist-3.4.GA.jar jta-1.1.jar
>   log4j.jar slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
>   slf4j-log4j12.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following files were missing:

> ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
>
> hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
>
> xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar